# how to render django-taggit common tags in template

Tags: django-templates, django-taggit

I've seen a lot of questions and answers about how to get most common tags using django-taggit. However that's not really my issue. My issue is how to pass that common tags to my django templates.

To return all tags I had:

```
{% for tag in model.tags.all %}
   <p>{{tag}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

And that worked fine. But how do I return the common tags in the *template*? To get the common tags I have this:

```
class Home(ListView):
    model = Model
    template_name = 'home.html'

    def get_common_tags(self):
        common_tags = Model.tags.most_common()[:2]
        return common_tags
```

But how do I access these `common_tags`? Do I need to get the common tags from the template or should I be passing them from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is better to read about Django GCBV.

in your case:

```
class Home(ListView):
    model = Model
    template_name = 'home.html'

    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['common_tags'] = self.get_common_tags()
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

here we override `get_context_data`, to get in template variable `common_tags`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data

after that, in template:
¶

```
{% for tag in model.tags.all %}
   <p>{{tag}}</p>
{% endif %}
   <p> Most common tag are: {{ common_tags }}</p>
```

common_tags - is a list, you can made something with django template filter, like `join`:

```
{{ common_tags|join:" ," }}
```

or `unordered_list`:

```
 <ul>{{ common_tags|unordered_list }}</ul>
```

more - here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered-list

Comment: Awesome. I was also able to for loop through common_tags as well to create a list of <a> tags, which is what I wanted. Thanks again.